# python testing my method

Tags: python, testing

Hey guys i have a quick question about testing my method. Im new to python as of last week but im trying. My assignment was to make a method that takes of list of cards and sorts em in a certain fashion. I know all my checks and and if statements and such work because i tested them in a python shell, but i figured if i put all my code into the shell it would be out of index(correct indentation). So if you guys could help the thing im just not sure about is how to implement my method.

here is my method:

```
def play(list):

    for k in list:
        a,x,z = 0
        #insert into the pile
        pile = []
        pile = pile + [[list[k]]]

        #check if the new card in the pile is compatible to the card 3 to the left

        #check in terms if the first char of each card is compatible 
        if( (((pile[a])[(len(pile[a]))-1])[0] ) == ((((pile[a-3])[(len(pile[a-3]))-1])[0])) ):
            #add card to the top of the card 3 to left
            pile[a-3] = pile[a-3] + [((pile[a])[(len(pile[a]))-1])]
            if (len(pile[a])) == 1:
                del pile[a]
            else:
                del (pile[a])[-1]

        #check in terms if the last char of each card is compatible 
        elif((((pile[a])[(len(pile[a]))-1])[(len((((pile[a])[(len(pile[a]))-1]))))-1]) == (((pile[a-3])[(len(pile[a-3]))-1])[(len((((pile[a-3])[(len(pile[a-3]))-1]))))-1])):
            #add card to the top of the card 3 to left
            pile[a-3] = pile[a-3] + [((pile[a])[(len(pile[a]))-1])]
            if (len(pile[a])) == 1:
                del pile[a]
            else:
                del (pile[a])[-1]

        #check if the new card in the pile is compatible to the card to the left 

        #check in terms if the first char of each card is compatible 
        elif((((pile[a])[(len(pile[a]))-1])[0] ) == ((((pile[a-1])[(len(pile[a-1]))-1])[0]))):
            pile[a-1] = pile[a-1] + [((pile[a])[(len(pile[a]))-1])]
            if (len(pile[a])) == 1:
                del pile[a]
            else:
                del (pile[a])[-1]

        #check in terms if the last char of each card is compatible 
        elif( (((pile[a])[(len(pile[a]))-1])[(len((((pile[a])[(len(pile[a]))-1]))))-1]) == (((pile[a-1])[(len(pile[a-1]))-1])[(len((((pile[a-1])[(len(pile[a-1]))-1]))))-1])):
            pile[a-1] = pile[a-1] + [((pile[a])[(len(pile[a]))-1])]
            if (len(pile[a])) == 1:
                del pile[a]
            else:
                del (pile[a])[-1]

        else:
            a = a + 1  

        #now go through and look for additional moves 
        #(if any match the 1 to the left or 3rd)

        while x < (len(pile)):
            if((((pile[x])[(len(pile[x]))-1])[0] ) == ((((pile[x-3])[(len(pile[x-3]))-1])[0]))):
                pile[x-3] = pile[x-3] + [((pile[x])[(len(pile[x]))-1])]
                if (len(pile[x])) == 1:
                    del (pile[x])[-1]
                    z = x + 1
                    while z < (len(pile)):
                        pile[z-1] = pile[z]
                        z = z + 1
                    del pile[(len(pile))-1]
                else:
                    del (pile[x])[-1]
                x = x + 1

            elif((((pile[x])[(len(pile[x]))-1])[(len((((pile[x])[(len(pile[x]))-1]))))-1]) == (((pile[x-3])[(len(pile[x-3]))-1])[(len((((pile[x-3])[(len(pile[x-3]))-1]))))-1])):
                pile[x-3] = pile[x-3] + [((pile[x])[(len(pile[x]))-1])]
                if (len(pile[a])) == 1:
                    del (pile[x])[-1]
                    z = x + 1
                    while z < (len(pile)):
                        pile[z-1] = pile[z]
                        z = z + 1
                else:
                    del (pile[a])[-1]        
                x = x + 1

            elif((((pile[x])[(len(pile[x]))-1])[0] ) == ((((pile[x-1])[(len(pile[x-1]))-1])[0]))):
                pile[x-1] = pile[x-1] + [((pile[x])[(len(pile[x]))-1])]
                if (len(pile[x])) == 1:
                    del (pile[x])[-1]
                    z = x + 1
                    while z < (len(pile)):
                        pile[z-1] = pile[z]
                        z = z + 1
                    del pile[(len(pile))-1]
                else:
                    del (pile[x])[-1]
                x = x + 1

            elif( (((pile[x])[(len(pile[x]))-1])[(len((((pile[x])[(len(pile[x]))-1]))))-1]) == (((pile[x-1])[(len(pile[x-1]))-1])[(len((((pile[x-1])[(len(pile[x-1]))-1]))))-1])):
                pile[x-1] = pile[x-1] + [((pile[x])[(len(pile[x]))-1])]
                if (len(pile[a])) == 1:
                    del (pile[x])[-1]
                    z = x + 1
                    while z < (len(pile)):
                        pile[z-1] = pile[z]
                        z = z + 1
                else:
                    del (pile[x])[-1]
                x = x + 1

            else:
                x = x + 1

        #end while loop
    #end of for loop
    return pile
```

and this is like what my teacher gave me, like the test cases:

```
import unittest
import solitaire

class Test(unittest.TestCase):

def test1(self):
    actual   = solitaire.play(['AC','2C','3C','4C','5C','6C','7C','8C','9C','TC','JC','QC','KC',
                               'AD','2D','3D','4D','5D','6D','7D','8D','9D','TD','JD','QD','KD',
                               'AH','2H','3H','4H','5H','6H','7H','8H','9H','TH','JH','QH','KH',
                               'AS','2S','3S','4S','5S','6S','7S','8S','9S','TS','JS','QS','KS'] )
    expected = [['AS','2S','3S','4S','5S','6S','7S','8S','9S','TS','JS','QS','KS','KH','QH','JH','TH','9H','8H','7H','6H','5H','4H','3H','2H','AH','AD','2D','3D','4D','5D','6D','7D','8D','9D','TD','JD','QD','KD','KC','QC','JC','TC','9C','8C','7C','6C','5C','4C','3C','2C','AC']]
    self.assertEqual    ( len(expected), len(actual), 'Incorrect result' )
    self.assertListEqual(     expected,      actual,  'Incorrect result' )
    pass

def test2(self):
    actual   = solitaire.play(['QS','5D','4S','8D','8H','3C','3H','5C','9H','6S','QD','2S','2C',
                               'KS','QC','7C','JC','4H','3D','5S','6C','KD','JS','9C','TS','2D',
                               '4D','AS','AC','7H','TC','AH','KH','6D','4C','8C','TD','AD','8S',
                               '3S','JH','KC','QH','TH','6H','7S','5H','2H','9S','7D','JD','9D'] )
    expected = [['8D','8H','3H','3C','JC','7C','QC','QD','4D','4S','6S','KS','KD','5D','5C','2C','2S','QS'],
                ['9C','4C','4H','9H'],
                ['6D','2D','3D'],
                ['JS','TS','TC','6C','AC','AS','5S'],
                ['KH','AH','7H'],
                ['8C'],
                ['AD','TD'],
                ['3S','8S'],
                ['6H','TH','JH'],
                ['KC'],
                ['2H','QH'],
                ['9D','JD','7D','7S'],
                ['5H'],
                ['9S']]
    self.assertEqual    ( len(expected), len(actual), 'Incorrect result' )
    self.assertListEqual(     expected,      actual,  'Incorrect result' )
    pass

def test3(self):
    actual   = solitaire.play(['5S','9H','QH','2H','8H','6H','3S','3H','AS','5H','JH','3C','KH',
                               '4H','6S','8S','8D','2D','JD','AH','KC','TD','TC','3D','6D','2C',
                               'AD','QS','9C','7C','6C','QD','JS','7H','7S','7D','KD','TS','5D',
                               'KS','9S','9D','4C','5C','8C','QC','JC','TH','4S','4D','2S','AC'] )
    expected = [['4D','5D','5C','8C','QC','JC','4C','4S','TS','AS','AH','4H','5H','7H','7S','JS','QS','QD','AD','6D','3D','TD','JD','2D','8D','8S','6S','KS','KD','7D','9D','9C','7C','6C','2C','TC','3C','KC','KH','JH','9H','QH','2H','8H','6H','3H','3S','5S'],
                ['9S'],
                ['TH'],
                ['2S'],
                ['AC']]
    self.assertEqual    ( len(expected), len(actual), 'Incorrect result' )
    self.assertListEqual(     expected,      actual,  'Incorrect result' )
    pass

def test4(self):
    actual   = solitaire.play(['7C','9S','QC','4H','9D','3S','AD','9C','8H','AC','2D','9H','AH',
                               '5D','6C','QD','3H','TC','QS','2S','8D','7D','QH','6H','4C','3C',
                               'JS','JD','7H','TS','4S','TD','5H','KD','8C','KS','JC','6D','2H',
                               '5C','3D','KH','8S','JH','TH','KC','2C','5S','AS','4D','7S','6S'] )
    expected = [['3S','9S','9D','AD','AC','7C'],
                ['QD','8D','7D','2D','5D','5H','8H','4H','9H','9C','QC'],
                ['AH'],
                ['TC','6C'],
                ['6H','3H'],
                ['JD','JS','2S','QS'],
                ['QH'],
                ['5C','JC','8C','3C','4C'],
                ['7H'],
                ['6D','TD','KD','KS','4S','TS'],
                ['2H'],
                ['3D'],
                ['TH','KH'],
                ['AS','5S','8S'],
                ['JH'],
                ['2C','KC'],
                ['4D'],
                ['6S','7S']]
    self.assertEqual    ( len(expected), len(actual), 'Incorrect result' )
    self.assertListEqual(     expected,      actual,  'Incorrect result' )
    pass

def test5(self):
    actual   = solitaire.play(['6C','AC','7C','7D','KC','6S','9H','5C','JS','3S','TS','9D','JH',
                               'QD','2D','8H','QS','8D','8C','2S','TC','9C','9S','5H','4D','3C',
                               'JD','QC','AS','3H','TD','7H','KS','KH','AD','TH','KD','4C','2C',
                               'QH','3D','5D','7S','4S','6D','2H','AH','JC','8S','4H','5S','6H'] )
    expected = [['JC','QC','2C','2H','QH','AH','4H','6H','6D','3D','5D','JD','TD','TH','7H','7S','4S','4C','TC','3C','3H','5H','KH','KS','KD','8D','4D','AD','AS','9S','9C','KC','5C','8C','8H','9H','JH','JS','TS','3S','6S','QS','2S','2D','QD','9D','7D','7C','AC','6C'],
                ['5S','8S']]
    self.assertEqual    ( len(expected), len(actual), 'Incorrect result' )
    self.assertListEqual(     expected,      actual,  'Incorrect result' )
    pass

def test6(self):
    actual   = solitaire.play(['8S','7C','AS','5H','7H','9D','8C','8H','3H','TC','AH','KH','JH',
                               'JC','AD','9C','AC','QS','6H','KC','KS','5C','TS','3C','9H','7D',
                               '3S','4D','TD','QD','5D','9S','3D','6S','6D','8D','JS','2S','4C',
                               '4S','5S','6C','2D','4H','7S','2H','KD','TH','JD','QH','QC','2C'] )
    expected = [['5S','7S','JS','2S','4S','4C','4H','TH','QH','QC','6C','9C','AC','KC','KS','QS','3S','3C','5C','5D','QD','7D','4D','TD','TS','9S','6S','6D','3D','8D','2D','2H','KH','6H','9H','9D','AD','AS','AH','3H','5H','JH','JC','8C','TC','7C','7H','8H','8S'],
                ['JD','KD'],
                ['2C']]
    self.assertEqual    ( len(expected), len(actual), 'Incorrect result' )
    self.assertListEqual(     expected,      actual,  'Incorrect result' )
    pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
#import sys;sys.argv = ['', 'Test.testName']
unittest.main()
```

Because i just learned python idk that much but im just not sure how i would use that test 'class' i guess it's called.

Any idea's?

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: You're doing great! But try to clarify your question. I think you're asking if your python file is correct (go try it) and how to run tests (read the documentation I posted). If you don't know how to get a python file running look [here](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/interpreter.html#executable-python-scripts) and if you want to see how to deal with tests go [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html).

Comment: The point of using `unittest` is that it will tell you whether you got it right or not. You just have to save your `play` function in a file called `solitaire.py` (because the test program is trying to `import solitaire`, so you have to match that name), then just run the tester script. (If it's called, say, `solitairetest.py`, then type `python solitairetest.py` at a shell.) It'll give you a nice printout of which tests you passed, and, if you failed any, what went wrong.

Comment: Het Thanks @abarnert. i saved it as solitaire.py. so now do i do the `python solitairetest.py` in a python shell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like the `play` function should be in the `solitaire` module that is being imported. This means that the values being assigned to the variable `actual`:

```
 actual = solitaire.play()
```

are the results stored in the `pile` variable in the `play` function. The test functions then have the expected results stored in the variable `expected`. So you should have the `solitaire` module and the test script in the same directory and then just run:

```
 python test.py
```

and it should give you some feedback. Running what you have produces a few errors. Running the `play` function through the interpreter should give you some feedback on where you have errors.

**Edit:**

Edit after the OP's comment.

It doesn't matter what you call `pile` in the `play` function. It's being returned by the function, so when you do something like `actual = solitaire.play()` that's *returning* pile and assigning it to actual.

To take a step back, you have two pieces of code: the `play` function and the class `Test`. The way the code is setup these should be in two separate files, let's call them solitaire.py and test.py. The `play` function should be in the solitaire.py file, while the `Test` class should go in test.py. The test.py script is importing the functions from the solitaire.py file with the line

`import solitaire`

This allows you to do things like.

`actual = solitaire.play()`

This line basically amounts to saying "From the solitaire module use the play function and assign the data it returns to the variable actual." To run the script, make sure the solitaire and test files are in the same directory, and that directory is the working directory in the terminal. You then just enter `python test.py` into the terminal and let it run.

If you need further help understanding Python, how to run scripts, etc., take a look at something like [Learn Python the Hard Way](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/).

Comment: Hey thanks for your reply, so are you saying that maybe instead of pile i should call it actual? I was thinking that since im returning pile that would just be given to the value of actual? And you said you ran it? IDK how to run it? Do i just put my play method somewhere in `class Test` ? Thanks for your patience, like i said my teacher didnt teach us much, just the very very basics.

Comment: Edited the answer to answer some of your questions.